# Do accrued residency years transfer from France to the Netherlands?

Tags: visa, netherlands, residency

I'm moving from France (currently work visa) to the Netherlands (will be partnership visa). I have lived 4 years in France. Will the 4 years I have accrued transfer to the Netherlands towards fulfilling the requirement for a permanent residency ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that can be called “permanent residence” but in general the clock resets when you move to the Netherlands and I don't think the time spent in France will help you.

Having spent 4 years in France will not help getting the Dutch [permanent residence permit](https://ind.nl/en/extend-renew-and-change/permanent-residency/permanent-residence-permit) (*Verblijfsvergunning onbepaalde tijd* or “unlimited time residence”) or the EU long-term residence status (*Verblijfsvergunning EU-langdurig*) in the Netherlands. For both of these, you will need to live 5 years in the Netherlands. If you learn the language and fulfil the other requirements, you can also apply for citizenship around the same time.

The one exception that could be relevant to you if you are currently staying in France on an EU Blue Card (your French residence permit would say something like “*Passeport talent – Carte Bleue Européenne*” on the back but they are not very common in France) and moving to the Netherlands under the same status. Then you can get both the EU long-term resident status and the Dutch permanent residence faster. The 4 years do not exactly “transfer”, the rules are more complicated than that but they allow you to get a kind of permanent status within 2 years instead of 5. Since you mentioned a partnership visa, this probably doesn't apply here.

There are also special rules for people who already gained the EU long-term resident status in another EU country but since you need 5 years to get that, I assume this is not the case for you in France at the moment. Finally, for completeness, there are also special rules for people who lived in the Netherlands during their childhood or used to be Dutch citizens.